# Selecting an outer edge of a surface in catia

Tags: vba, visual-studio, catia

I am trying to extrapolate a surface which is an assemble of 6 surfaces. To get a referance for extrapolate, i need to get a outer edge. How can i make sure to referance an outer edge of a surface. Is there any example of it.

Thank you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an algorithm, i got boundary of the surface, disassembled it than selected a random curve. It worked.